# best design practice in PHP for navigating from one form to another

Tags: php

I have an application in which I display a form so a user can search for client records based on last name. After entering search parameters, the record or records (there could be multiple clients with the same last name) are displayed. I then want the user to be able to select a client record, possibly with a radio button, and hit one of two buttons: Display details, or Create Reservation. The Display Details button should cause a new display with details of the selected record. The Create Reservation button should cause a new form, with its own handling, to be displayed.

Now, I know I can set things up according to this login

```
<?php
if (display button was pressed)
  {  
     php code to retrieve more data and display details
  }
else if (create reservation button was pressed)
{
    php code to generate and display the reservation form, with appropriate handling
 }
?>
```

display the original form with the search results

The problem is, I end up with really ugly, hard to read code because the php code to generate and display the reservation form is lengthy, and needs its own validation, database interaction, and form handling. The code, to my Java-oriented eye, looks ugly and non-modular. Plus, the code  for handling the reservation form is icky, with lots of flag setting to determine if we are in form entry mode or form handling mode. I would like a much cleaner way to do this. So my question is, what is the best practice for handling the situation where there are multiple buttons and the action associated with each button is complex?

I could call a function, obviously, but I still end up with the ugly flags determining which state the script is in (are we displaying the reservation form or handling it?). I could create another php file and include it, but the ugliness persists. Or, I could use header, and pass the client record id in a session variable to the new php script. But that would mean a second, unnecessary retrieve from the database to get the client information again.

All the code examples I see on the web show very simple processing after a form button is pressed. What is the best way to do complex processing and displaying a second form based on a button press?

Comment: That's why good PHP developers maintain an MVC style separation... if you're used to java, then you should be familiar with that approach to coding

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a framework like Laravel for your site. It would seem to me that you must be doing this "manually". With the complexities you described, having a system with routes and "build-in" functionality (like Eloquent ORM) might serve to simplify things for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for using ajax and a rich jQuery plugin (or some other framework) to do what you want.

Basically you will handle lists and the functionality that you mentioned with the php reading data and jQuery scripts to dysplay it. And the information that you have to show would be through ajax. Or when you want to edit.

Here is a cleaner example of what you need:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: OK, so this is something that is hard to do in straight PHP? I am surprised - it seems like something that would be commonly required. I am trying to keep this in straight PHP due to the skillset of the person I need to hand this off to. I am not a web developer myself in fact, but am doing this to help out.

Comment: It is not too hard. And add a jQuery script to your page will be painless because it is client script (assuming here that you know the difference between client and server). So, the main problem that i see is how is your logic structured, depending on that it can be very difficult or incredible easy. You will do it with just php will will add a jquery or some other client framework to improve your html functionalities.

Comment: I'm leaving my house now. When I came back, maybe tomorrow at launch time, I will create a simple sample with something near what you need, using just jquery, mysql and php to show you how easy it can be. I will post it here.